# Strike-through text: Microsoft Lync

Tags: instant-messaging, lync

Somehow I hit a magic key combination in Microsoft Lync that is sending strike-through text.  When I look at the "A" icon (text properties), I don't see an option for strike-through.

How can I disable strike-through text in MS Lync?

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> is the keyboard shortcut for striking through text, according to [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/communicator-help/keyboard-shortcuts-for-lync-2010-HA101832602.aspx) document from Microsoft. While it doesn't specify that it's a toggle, I would try pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> again to see if that disables strikethrough.

Comment: There's something funny where you have to start a new line of text, but ctrl-T does toggle.

Comment: Worst case, is to close the window and re-open.So that it would display normally.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will end the strikthrough.

Comment: This is exactly what worked for more, Ctrl-T didn't do anything for me on Lync 2010

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue, try using this:
Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and press <kbd>Z</kbd> twice. I was able to get rid of strikethroughs.

Answer (score 1):

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will get rid of the strikethrough. If you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, you'll get the strikethrough again. It happened to me, and that's how I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Right click in Text typing area and select 'Change IM Font' which will display Font setting pop up

Answer (score -1):

Right click in Text Box
Change IM Font....
under Effects 
un check StrikeOut